# Wait to load child views in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with 3 child views connected in Storyboard.

Im doing my API business in the TabBarControllers custom class. This is async.

The child views are all getting information from the parent TabBarController.

Problem:

All the childs are only getting the dummy data because they are loaded before the API call has been finished.

Is there a way to "delay" loading the childs? Something I can call in the async tasks oncomplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could start with an empty tab bar controller and add the child view controllers programmatically as the API call completes.

However, this begs the question, why show the tab bar controller at all? Instead, I'd suggest that you start with an empty 'loading' screen and segue to the tab bar controller when the API call completes.

I'd also suggest that, rather than subclassing `TabBarController` for your API calls, you create a separate manager object to perform the update process, potentially as a singleton object (depending on other code considerations). You can then either call the shared instance from your view controllers, or inject the API call manager directly into each instance in `prepare(for segue: sender:)` on the presenting / parent view controller.

Comment: Thanks for your insight on this. I will go for your suggestion and rewrite my code for this as it seems a lot better